# Intercepting QGIS panels closings?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

I would like to be able to intercept **QGIS panels** (QDockWidgets) **closings**.

I read the API online help but i don't clearly understand it.Is there any usable close signal linked with dockWidgets?

In a next step i would like to implement my **own** QDockWidgets with their own behaviour but ... how can i achieve this for existing integrated QGIS panels?

Comment: Have you tried the `visibilityChanged` or `destroyed` signal for your purposes? https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html Also, what QGIS and Qt version?

Comment: I am on QGIS 2.18 so far. `visibilityChanged` seems to fit my needs. `destroyed` signal doesn't seem to give anything ...

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do so from the Python console, or are you actually working on QGIS source code?

In any case, QDockWidget **does not** emit a signal when closing. You should write your own class, derived from QDockWidget, and reimplement the [closeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) method, which is called whenever the widget is closed.

From there, you can emit a custom signal, if you need to notify the close event to the outside world.

Comment: yeah that's what i feared ... and no similar signal or inherited one ? does that mean there is nothing to do with the existing QGIS panels ? Maybe replace them with my customized one ? My aim is to develop a plug-in but i make some tests in the console. Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But if you already have a pointer to that panel you can check its status with the [visible()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop) property.

Answer (score 1):

As S Monteleone pointed out there's no direct signal emitted by a QDockWidget when it's closed. However, there's still a close event fired. This means you can install a Qt event filter on the widget which intercepts close events and emits it's own signal to indicate that the dock was closed.

You'll need to do some reading on event filters - they are quite a powerful concept in Qt.

Comment: Thanks ! i'll work on this ... i'm playing with the **visibilityChanged** signal so far since destroyed signal doesn't seem to give anything visible ...